# where are the head file in /usr/include from? Linux kernel code Or Gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

we also include some head file in our C file? like this

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

these file are all in /usr/include.
however, where are these file in /usr/include/ from?
Are them from Linux kernel Code Or gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both come from GlibC; usually kernel header files are in `/usr/include/linux` and other subdirs, while gcc includes are located elsewhere (like `/usr/lib/<arch>/<version>/include`)